# PowerCLI Move-VM Returns failure but vm still moves

Tags: powershell, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, powercli

I have a script that is moving VM's from one datastore to another. I have other logic to protect the Storage backend and fabric from over subscription and to wait to submit new requests at specific times (Business requirement). I am only moving datastores and not hosts. I have a try catch block around the Move-VM as I want to handle the failure. The first two or three times I ran the script only a few errors occur and were handled as I expected. The last 5 times the move returns an error but the VM move request is successful as indicated by the task I see in vCenter. This job completes successfully as well. The Move-VM is not using the RunAsync switch. What would cause Move-VM to return an error but successfully submit the move request.

```
$VMs = Get-VM -Name $ComputerName
$CurrentDataStores = Get-Datastore

foreach ($VM in $VMs){
   foreach ($store in $CurrentDataStores){
      if ($store.name -eq "$Datastore"){
         $rawDatastore = $store
      }
      if ($store.id -Match $VM.DatastoreIdList){
         $VMDatastore = $store.name
      } 
   }
   if ($VMDatastore -eq "$Datastore"){
      Write-Output "$VM : is already on requested Datastore"
   }
   else{
      try {
          Move-VM -VM $VM -Datastore $rawDatastore -ErrorAction Stop
      }
      catch {
         Write-OutPut "$VM : Unable to move VM to new Datastore" 
         continue
      }
   }
}

Move-VMDatastore : <VM Name> : Unable to move VM to new Datastore
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-VMDatastore -ComputerName <VM Name> -Datastore <Move TO Datastore>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Move-VMDatastore


Move-VMDatastore : 12/24/2014 12:50:02 AM    Move-VM        Operation is not valid due to the current state of the
object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-VMDatastore -ComputerName <ComputerName[]> -Datastore <Datastore>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Move-VMDatastore
```

Comment: It's really gonna help if you gave the exact text of the error. Also, your code.

Comment: True. Edit to add code.

Comment: Change your catch block to "Write-Error $_" to see the actual error Move-VM is throwing. That will help identify the real issue.

Comment: I will do that and report the new error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of this issue is that in the implementation of Move-VM, PowerCLI runs an async task, gets the task and then runs `Wait-Task` on it.

If the operation is very fast, it will fail with this issue. This is an educated guess stemming from the fact that this is the exact exception you get when you `Wait-Task` for a completed task.

So basically your problem is that your VMware server is *too fast*...

A workaround would be to use the -RunAsync switch and implement the correct behaviour yourself. Something like:

```
$Task = Move-VM -VM $VM -Datastore $rawDatastore -ErrorAction Stop -RunAsync
while($true)
{
    switch ($task.State)
    {
         'Success' { $Task.Result; break }
         'Error' { throw $Task.ExtensionData.Info.Error.LocalizedMessage }
         Start-Sleep 5
    }
}
```

Edit: I have seen the exact same issue with Stop-VM and Remove-VM and have worked around them the same way

This issue has been submitted for improvement to the PowerCLI team here:
https://powercli.ideas.aha.io/ideas/PCLI-I-208

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else comes across this issue, it would appear that the $task variable doesn't update by itself. In my case, I had to do:

```
 while($task.state -eq "Running")
 {
   Start-Sleep 5
   $task = Get-Task -ID $task.id
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had this issue too.  It seems like something causes the connection from the powercli to the vcenter server to corrupt.  Each time I run it after the fact produces the same error.  I have to close my command window and open a brand new window to resolve the issue.